# How can get the closes object from object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I'm trying to get the closest object from object array. if there is not matched element, I'd like to get the most closest one from array? Here are the examples:
for example, let's assume that the array is as following:

```
const array = [
  { element1: 50, element2: 100, element3: 200, element4: 90 },
  { element1: 150, element2: 110, element3: 200, element4: 190 },
  { element1: 250, element2: 120, element3: 190, element4: 290 },
  { element1: 350, element2: 130, element3: 120, element4: 390 },
  { element1: 450, element2: 140, element3: 140, element4: 490 },
  { element1: 550, element2: 150, element3: 160, element4: 590 },
]
```

and I set the value on settings as following: `{ element1: 60, element2: 100, element3: 200, element4: 100 },`,

Then actually, there is no element matched with this one on the array. and at that time, it returns the most closest one from them. in that case, the first element would be returned - `{ element1: 50, element2: 100, element3: 200, element4: 90 }`.

Comment: You could start by defining what it means to be the closest. Is it the sum of the differences of each element? Then you just need to loop through your array and check against your target for example. If the sum is 0, then you found an exact match, otherwise you keep comparing with your target. But you should try it by yourself first and come up with more specific questions.

Comment: Is it the individual difference of each element or does it mean sum of all properties in each object?

Comment: It's the individual difference of each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` then sorting the values based on the output:

```js
var array = [ { element1: 50, element2: 100, element3: 200, element4: 90 }, { element1: 150, element2: 110, element3: 200, element4: 190 }, { element1: 250, element2: 120, element3: 190, element4: 290 }, { element1: 350, element2: 130, element3: 120, element4: 390 }, { element1: 450, element2: 140, element3: 140, element4: 490 }, { element1: 550, element2: 150, element3: 160, element4: 590 }];

var settings = { element1: 60, element2: 100, element3: 200, element4: 100 };

var [difference, result] = Object.entries(array.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  difference = 0;
  Object.keys(elem).forEach(k=>difference+=Math.abs(elem[k]-settings[k]));
  acc[difference] = acc[difference] || [];
  acc[difference].push(elem);
  return acc;
},{})).sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1])[0];

console.log(result);
console.log(difference)
```

Comment: @pavel1117, Sure thing, Also I have update my answer, it will now return the list of closest element in an array. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function objectDistance(obj1, obj2) {
  return (
    obj1.element1 +
    obj1.element2 +
    obj1.element3 +
    obj1.element4 -
    obj2.element1 -
    obj2.element2 -
    obj2.element3 -
    obj2.element4
  );
}

array.map(function (x) {
  objectDistance(x, toCompare);
});
```

This map function returns an array of the distances, all you have to do is calculate the minimum value and access your object array and return it.
Note: not a js guy but the concepts should be right.